# how to customize Material-react-table edit modal customized input box as select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

In Material-react-table how to customize the edit modal input box as select dropdown instead of Text field and I'm unable to achieve the customized dropdown in column of material-react-table .I used editComponent, muiEditTextFieldProps, onEditingCellChange and unable to achieve the customized dropdown select from react-select    {
accessorKey: 'teachername',
header: 'Class Teacher',
enableEditing: true,

```
        },
```

I need an customization material-react-table edit modal for particular column and I'm unable to achieve through these edit feature guide editComponent, muiEditTextFieldProps, onEditingCellChange